# Server Object Model to get Users & Group details of Site Collection and it's site levels

Tags: csom, ssom

I am new to programming , And seeking desperate help from you folks .
Need to get all the users of Site Collection ,Even on breaking in-heritance between sites and sub-sites.

Can any one help me how can I do this via SharePoint server object model

Answer (score 3):

Try like this for getting the groups and users in site collection

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace Framework.Business.Components
{ 
            /// <summary>
            /// UsersCollection is object to get all users by selected web object.
            /// </summary> 
            public class UsersCollection
            {
                        private ArrayList    _usersListCollection;   //All incomming users.
                        private SPWeb       _selectedWeb;           //Web position.
                        private string         _groupName;            //Group name.

                    private const string _allGroups  = "ALL_GROUPS";

                    /// <summary>
                    /// SPWebLocation property.
                    /// </summary>
                    public SPWeb SPWebLocation
                    {
                               get{return _selectedWeb;}
                               set{_selectedWeb = value;}
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// SPGroupName property.
                    /// </summary>
                    public string SPGroupName
                    {
                               get{return _groupName;}
                               set{_groupName = value;}
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// To run the example you need to initialize the UsersCollection object with two instance website and GroupName objects.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="webSite">SPWeb object</param>
                    /// <param name="groupName">string group name</param>
                    public UsersCollection(SPWeb webSite ,string groupName)
                    {    
                               //Check if the SPWeb object is not null.
                               if(webSite != null)
                               {
                                           if(groupName == null || groupName.Length == 0)
                                           {     
                                                       this.SPGroupName = _allGroups;
                                           }
                                           _usersListCollection = new ArrayList();

                               }
                               else
                               {
                                           Console.WriteLine("ERROR WEB LOCATION: Your web location have a null value.");
                               }
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// This public method get all users from SharePoint web location and get user related information.
                    /// </summary>
                    public ArrayList GetUsersByGroup()
                    {
                               if(this.SPGroupName == _allGroups)
                               {
                                           foreach(SPGroup singleGroup in this.SPWebLocation.Groups)
                                           {
                                                       UsersList(singleGroup);
                                           }
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                           SPGroup singleGroup = this.SearchGroup(this._groupName);
                                           if(singleGroup != null)
                                           {
                                                       this.UsersList(singleGroup);
                                           }
                                           else
                                           {
                                                       Console.WriteLine("ERROR WEB GROUP: " +  this._groupName + " GROUP NOT EXIST.");
                                           }
                               }
                               return _usersListCollection;
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// This private method get users by selected SPGroup object.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="group">SPGroup object</param>
                    private void UsersList(SPGroup group)
                    {
                               foreach(SPUser singleUser in group.Users)
                               {
                                           foreach(SPRole singleRole in singleUser.Roles)
                                           {
                                                       _usersListCollection.Add(new UserListCollection(
                                                           singleUser.LoginName,singleRole.Name,group.ParentWeb.Title));
                                           }
                               }
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// This method search for SPGroup name.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="group">string</param>
                    /// <returns>SPGroup object</returns>
                    private SPGroup SearchGroup(string group)
                    {
                               SPGroup groupObject = null;
                               foreach(SPGroup singleGroup in this.SPWebLocation.Groups)
                               {
                                           if(group == singleGroup.Name)
                                           {
                                                       groupObject = singleGroup;
                                           }
                               }
                               return groupObject;
                    }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic class UserListCollection
        /// </summary> 
        public class UserListCollection
        {
                    private string _userName = "";
                    private string _userRole = "";
                    private string _userWeb = "";

                    /// <summary>
                    /// Generic username.
                    /// </summary>
                    public string UserName
                    {
                               get { return _userName; }
                               set { _userName = value; }
                    }


                    /// <summary>
                    /// Generic user role.
                    /// </summary>
                    public string UserRole
                    {
                               get { return _userRole; }
                               set { _userRole = value; }
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// Generic SharePoint web name.
                    /// </summary>
                    public string WebName
                    {
                               get { return _userWeb; }
                               set { _userWeb = value; }
                    }

                    /// <summary>
                    /// This constructor insert three values.
                    /// </summary>
                    /// <param name="userName">Name of NT user account.</param>
                    /// <param name="userGroup">SharePoint web group name.</param>
                    /// <param name="userWeb">SPSite web name.</param>
                    public UserListCollection(string userName, string userGroup, string userWeb)
                    {
                               this.UserName   = userName;
                               this.UserRole     = userGroup;
                               this.WebName   = userWeb;
                    }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example to run UsersCollection class.
        /// </summary>
        class Example
        {
                    /// <summary>
                    /// Example to get all users info with generic UsersCollection class.
                    /// </summary>
                    public static void GetUsers()
                    {
                               //Url location object.
                               Uri url = new Uri("http://localserver/");

                               SPGlobalAdmin globalAdmin = new SPGlobalAdmin();
                               SPVirtualServer  virtualServer = globalAdmin.OpenVirtualServer(url);

                               //Get all users by site position and group.
                               UsersCollection user = new UsersCollection(
                                           virtualServer.Sites[0].AllWebs[0],"Reader");

                               ArrayList usersArray = user.GetUsersByGroup();
                               for(int i = 0;i < usersArray.Count;i++)
                               {
                                           //Generic class
                                           UserListCollection userExample = (UserListCollection)usersArray[i];
                                           Console.WriteLine("UserName: " + userExample.UserName);
                                           Console.WriteLine("Role: " + userExample.UserRole);
                                           Console.WriteLine("Web: " + userExample.WebName);
                               }
                    }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

1. Need to write server-side for reading all webs from your site collection.
2. Need to iterate all the groups with in the webs.
3. after that all need to iterate all the Sp-user Groups and each group will return the user properties.